# Python, how to print dictionary key and its values in each line?

Tags: python, dictionary

Please see the below image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Image is not uploaded, kindly upload.

Comment: I can't see an image ... however in order to paste code into your question, just add four spaces at the beginning of every line -  then it will be displayed in `code style`. Adding an image of code is not appreciated, as it doesn't allow copy and paste.

Comment: Well - this is not possible, because each key must have a unique value. You cannot have two values to the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a single `for loop` unpacking a value list each iteration.

```
d = {1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 5]}

for k in d:
    x, y = d[k]
    print("{} : {}\n{} : {}".format(k, x, k, y))

1 : 2
1 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
```

Because the value lists have just a couple numbers, it can also be done, like so:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print("{} : {}\n{} : {}".format(k, v[0], k, v[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for key in d:
...     for item in d[key]:
...         print key, ':', item
1 : 2
1 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
d = {1:[2,3], 2:[4,5]}

for key in d:
    for i in d[key]:
        print("{0}:{1}".format(key, i))


1:2
1:3
2:4
2:5
```

Answer (score 1):

use `key` and `value` of your dictionary

```
d={1:[2,3],2:[4,5]}
for k, v in d.items():
    for item in v:
        print(k,' : ',item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended it further to get data printed in table form by printing Keys on top and relevant data under each key

```
d= {10:[2,3],20:[4,5],30:[6,7],40:[8,9]}
for k in d:
    x10, y10 = d[10]
    x20, y20 = d[20]
    x30, y30 = d[30]
    x40, y40 = d[40]
    if k == 10:
        print("{}".format(k), end="")
    elif k == 20 or k == 30 or k==40:
        print(" : {}".format(k), end="")
        if k==40:
            print("\n{}     {}    {}    {}".format(x10, x20, x30, x40))
            print("{}     {}    {}    {}".format(y10, y20, y30, y40))
            break
```